After upgrading from angular 14 to 17 RouterModule and custom pipes are broken, giving lots of errors
I almost don't know where to start. Hope you can give me some guidance. After upgrading my angular version to 17 I receive a lot of errors while executing ng serve or build.
I tried to work with standalone components for the custom pipes, that seem to work. I tried removing the brackets from routerlink links in the html files. That solved some of the issues, but the list of errors goes on and on and I have the feeling I'm doing something terribly wrong. At the end of this question I have pasted my app.module.ts, maybe there's a fix / error that solves it all. Thanks for having a look!
This is one of the errors:
error NG8002: Can't bind to 'routerLinkActive' since it isn't a known property of 'a'.
9         <div class=""><a [routerLink]="['/my-stuff/notifications']"  class="btn position-relative p-0 ps-2" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" #notifications="routerLinkActive">  <i *ngIf="!notifications.isActive" class="bi-envelope" style="font-size: 19.5px; color: black;"></i><i *ngIf="notifications.isActive" class="bi-envelope-fill" style="font-size: 19.5px; color: black;"></i><span *ngIf="notificationcount && notificationcount>0" class="position-absolute  top-0 start-100 translate-middle badge rounded-pill bg-primary">
And another:
error NG8003: No directive found with exportAs 'routerLinkActive'.
<div class=""><a [routerLink]="['/my-stuff/notifications']"  class="btn position-relative p-0 ps-2" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" #notifications="routerLinkActive">  <i *ngIf="!notifications.isActive" class="bi-envelope" style="font-size: 19.5px; color: black;"></i><i *ngIf="notifications.isActive" class="bi-envelope-fill" style="font-size: 19.5px; color: black;"></i><span *ngIf="notificationcount && notificationcount>0" class="position-absolute  top-0 start-100 translate-middle badge rounded-pill bg-primary">
This is one of the many custom pipe errors:
Error: src/app/notifications/notifications.component.html:21:47 - error NG8004: No pipe found with name 'dateago'.
21                                             | dateago }}</p>
This is this pipe:
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { formatDate } from "@angular/common";
import {Component,
  Inject,
  LOCALE_ID }
  from '@angular/core';


@Pipe({
  name: 'dateago',
})
export class DateagoPipe implements PipeTransform {

 

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    if (value) {
        const seconds = Math.floor((+new Date() - +new Date(value)) / 1000);
        if (seconds < 29) // less than 30 seconds ago will show as 'Just now'
            return 'Just now';
        if (seconds > 604800) // more than a week returns just the timestamp again
            return formatDate(value, 'mediumDate', this.locale) 
        const intervals: { [key: string]: number } = {
            'year': 31536000,
            'month': 2592000,
            'w': 604800,
            'd': 86400,
            'h': 3600,
            'm': 60,
            's': 1
        };
        let counter;
        for (const i in intervals) {
            counter = Math.floor(seconds / intervals[i]);
            if (counter > 0)
                if (counter === 1) {
                    return counter + ' ' + i // + ' ago'; // singular (1 day ago)
                } else {
                    return counter + ' ' + i // + 's ago'; // plural (2 days ago)
                }
        }
    }
    return value;
}
constructor(
  @Inject(LOCALE_ID) public locale: string,){}
}


My feeling is, I am doing something wrong in my app.module.ts
As here it all comes together. And also because the number of errors is so overwhelming.
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule }    from '@angular/common/http';
import { ClipboardModule } from 'ngx-clipboard';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { authInterceptorProviders } from './auth.interceptor';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TopBarComponent } from './top-bar/top-bar.component';
import { FeedComponent } from './feed/feed.component';
import { ListDetailsComponent } from './list-details/list-details.component';
import { ItemDetailsComponent } from './item-details/item-details.component';
import { DropComponent } from './drop/drop.component';
import { SavedComponent } from './saved/saved.component';
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { MessagesComponent } from './messages/messages.component';
import { BottomBarComponent } from './bottom-bar/bottom-bar.component';
import { ShortlistComponent } from './shortlist/shortlist.component';
import { OrdinalPipe } from './ordinal.pipe';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './profile/profile.component';
import { DropupdateComponent } from './dropupdate/dropupdate.component';
import { ChapterComponent } from './chapter/chapter.component';
import { UserComponent } from './user/user.component';
import { SearchComponent } from './search/search.component';
import { EditComponent } from './edit/edit.component';
import { DropsComponent } from './drops/drops.component';
import { ChaptersComponent } from './chapters/chapters.component';
import { LonglistComponent } from './longlist/longlist.component';
import { ListComponent } from './list/list.component';
import { LoadingComponent } from './loading/loading.component';
import { ClickableurlsPipe } from './clickableurls.pipe';
import { CopytoclipboardDirective } from './copytoclipboard.directive';
import { DateagoPipe } from './dateago.pipe';
import { AutofocusDirective } from './autofocus.directive';
import { ServiceWorkerModule } from '@angular/service-worker';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { TypeaheadModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/typeahead';
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { ChapterHeadingComponent } from './chapter-heading/chapter-heading.component';
import { RoutingGuardGuard } from './routing-guard.guard';
import { RegisterSuccessComponent } from './register-success/register-success.component';
import { RegisterAlmostDoneComponent } from './register-almost-done/register-almost-done.component';
import { RegisterCheckMailComponent } from './register-check-mail/register-check-mail.component';
import { PasswordForgotComponent } from './password-forgot/password-forgot.component';
import { PasswordUpdateComponent } from './password-update/password-update.component';
import { MyStuffComponent } from './my-stuff/my-stuff.component';
import { NotificationsComponent } from './notifications/notifications.component';
import { NewNotificationsService } from './new-notifications.service';
import { initializeApp,provideFirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { provideMessaging,getMessaging } from '@angular/fire/messaging';
import { FeedShellComponent } from './feed-shell/feed-shell.component';
import { SupportComponent } from './support/support.component';
import { MarketingComponent } from './marketing/marketing.component';
import { PrivacypolicyComponent } from './privacypolicy/privacypolicy.component';
import { NgxPullToRefreshModule } from 'ngx-pull-to-refresh';
import { TagInputModule } from 'ngx-chips';
import { ImagekitioAngularModule } from 'imagekitio-angular';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    NgbModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    TagInputModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgxPullToRefreshModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    ClipboardModule,
    ImagekitioAngularModule.forRoot({
      publicKey: environment.publicKey,
      urlEndpoint: environment.urlEndpoint,
    }),
    TypeaheadModule.forRoot(),
    RouterModule.forRoot([
    { path: '', component: FeedComponent },
    { path: 'drop/:listId', component: DropupdateComponent, canActivate: [RoutingGuardGuard] },
    { path: 'drop', component: DropComponent, canActivate: [RoutingGuardGuard]  },
    { path: 'edit/:listId', component: EditComponent, canActivate: [RoutingGuardGuard]  },
    // { path: 'item/:listId/:list_creator/:position_id', component: ItemDetailsComponent},
    { path: 'item/:listId/:list_creator/:item_id', component: ItemDetailsComponent },
    { path: 'listdetails/:listId/:list_creator', component: ListDetailsComponent },
    { path: 'longlist/:listId', component: LonglistComponent },
    { path: 'lists/:listId', component: ListComponent },
    { path: 'my-stuff', component: SavedComponent, canActivate: [RoutingGuardGuard]   },
    { path: 'my-stuff/drops', component: DropsComponent, canActivate: [RoutingGuardGuard]   },
    { path: 'my-stuff/chapters', component: ChaptersComponent, canActivate: [RoutingGuardGuard]   },
    { path: 'my-stuff/profile', component: ProfileComponent, canActivate: [RoutingGuardGuard]   },
    { path: 'my-stuff/notifications', component: NotificationsComponent, canActivate: [RoutingGuardGuard]   },
    { path: 'profile/:user', component: UserComponent },
    { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
    { path: 'register/almost-done/:email/:username', component: RegisterAlmostDoneComponent },
    { path: 'register/check-mail', component: RegisterCheckMailComponent },
    { path: 'forgotpassword', component: PasswordForgotComponent },
    { path: 'changepassword/:username/:email/:token', component: PasswordUpdateComponent },
    { path: 'confirm/:email/:token', component: RegisterSuccessComponent },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'chapter/:chapter', component: ChapterComponent },
    { path: 'search/:search_term', component: SearchComponent },
    { path: 'search', component: SearchComponent },
    { path: 'support', component: SupportComponent },
    { path: 'marketing', component: MarketingComponent }, 
    { path: 'privacy-policy', component: PrivacypolicyComponent }, 
], {
    initialNavigation: 'enabledNonBlocking'
}),
    HttpClientModule,
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', {
      enabled: environment.production,
      // Register the ServiceWorker as soon as the application is stable
      // or after 30 seconds (whichever comes first).
      registrationStrategy: 'registerWhenStable:30000'
    }),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ModalModule.forRoot(),
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    provideMessaging(() => getMessaging()),

    // The HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule module intercepts HTTP requests
    // and returns simulated server responses.
    // Remove it when a real server is ready to receive requests.
    // HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(
    //   InMemoryDataService, { dataEncapsulation: false }
    // )
  ],
  exports: [
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CommonModule,
    TopBarComponent,
    FeedComponent,
    ListDetailsComponent,
    ItemDetailsComponent,
    DropComponent,
    SavedComponent,
    MessagesComponent,
    BottomBarComponent,
    ShortlistComponent,
    OrdinalPipe,
    RegisterComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    ProfileComponent,
    DropupdateComponent,
    ChapterComponent,
    UserComponent,
    SearchComponent,
    EditComponent,
    DropsComponent,
    ChaptersComponent,
    LonglistComponent,
    ListComponent,
    LoadingComponent,
    ClickableurlsPipe,
    CopytoclipboardDirective,
    DateagoPipe,
    AutofocusDirective,
    ChapterHeadingComponent,
    RegisterSuccessComponent,
    RegisterAlmostDoneComponent,
    RegisterCheckMailComponent,
    PasswordForgotComponent,
    PasswordUpdateComponent,
    MyStuffComponent,
    NotificationsComponent,
    FeedShellComponent,
    SupportComponent,
    MarketingComponent,
    PrivacypolicyComponent,
  ],
  providers: [authInterceptorProviders, DatePipe, NewNotificationsService],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }



Hope you can get me on track again. Thanks so much for looking into this. Feel free to mention any missing information as well, will try to update this too.

is your github repo public?

I got it locally, happy to share things if that would help

maybe share the github repo for debugging, could be multiple issues, require debugging through stackblitz so, github repo needed!

Are you able to view this: https://github.com/planetstarbuck/planetstarbucks/tree/main

With your upgrade process did you perform a full build and deployment of each iteration or did you just upgrade to 17 and then do the build / deployment?

I tried to stick as closely as possible to the checklist angular gave me, however I have not done a successful build/deployment on angular 15 for instance. Reason is, it said to upgrade angular because I updated I think some other (node?) modules. Which I did, and here it told me it was only working with the newest angular, of which I started to upgrade to expecting it to solve all, by being up-to-date. This might be too quick thinking of mine. I didnt code on this app for a while and wanting to add a feature. Are there steps I can follow now to ensure everything is ok on my environment?

Did you find the error with this?

Hi Alfredo, unfortunately not, I didnt spend too much time on the project recently. My idea is to start from scratch in the future, but thats not a very appealing future of course. Do you got the exact same kind of issues?
